# Hibernate Mapping

Tags: hibernate, mapping

i want write a mapping File for following Class, but i dont know how.

```
public class TwoDimHashMap<K1, K2, I> {
   private final Map<K1, Map<K2, I>> main;
   public TwoDimHashMap() {
      main = new HashMap<K1, Map<K2, I>>();
   }
...
}
```

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mapping a Map](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#d0e10663) is pretty straightforward in Hibernate. I don't believe a Map of Maps is possible, and neither is it usually desirable. For example, instead of a Map, it's usually easier and more expressive to use a Set<Something> where Something is a mapped class with two String properties. Doing it this way is usually a more natural expression of your problem domain, and it's *far* easier to write queries on this kind of model than querying into a Map.